# Emulator constantly freezes when typing to the input field from keyboard

Tags: flutter

Emulator constantly freezes when typing to the input field from keyboard. 
All the tools are updated. Flutter doctor is ok.
What else can I do to fix it?

Almost every time I type from keybord I get the error

> qemu-system-x86_64.exe does not respond

Answer (score 0):

can you check the Ram allocated to Emulator please increase if possible, and check the free space on you Laptop/Desktop if there is less space it will stuck